# After upgrading typescript version from 2.0.1 to 2.4.1 get the following error in angular 2 application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

When I upgrade my typescript version from 2.0.1 to 2.4.1 then I am facing the following problem...

[image]

Comment: delete the node_module and also update the other package version in package.json and npm install

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the latest version of TypeScript, you should also use the latest version of `rxjs` (and angular). The new version of TypeScript revealed a 'bug' inside the typings of rxjs. Set `"rxjs": "5.4.2"` in your package json and update and you are good to go.

Check for any other outdated dependencies using

```
npm outdated
```

Also make sure before any big update to remove your entire `node_modules` folder and your `package-lock.json`

Comment: then first delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and install again